# Change color of insert mark when changing the column order

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

When you click on a ColumnHeader in a GridView and drag the column header, there is a marking, where the column will be inserted, when you release the button. How can the color of this insert mark be changed?

Comment: You mean the black line that appears between columns? I think that's hard coded. It was back when I had that requirement myself. Could have changed as that was pre 4.5 iirc.

Comment: On my system, this line is blue. But yes, I mean the line that appears between columns while dragging a columnheader.

Answer (score 1):

The drop location indicator of the column header is configured and templated internally. There is no chance to customize it gracefully (without extending default classes like the `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` and `GridView`) i.e. via an API (as exposed by the `DataGrid`).

A simple solution is to search the `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` in the visual tree of the `ListView` to observe mouse input (there are no drag events involved in the actual drag operation). By observing the mouse input, we can identify a drag operation.

During the drag operation, the `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` will add a `Separator` to its children. The configuration (layout and appearance) of this `Separator` is hard-coded. If we lookup this `Separator`, we can modify its appearance (for example the `Background` brush).

Sadly, the `Style` that is applied to the drop locator `Separator` does not connect the template's internal `Border.Background` to the templated parent's `Separator.Background` property: the `Border.Background` of the `Border` that makes the `Separator.Template`, is hard-coded too. This means we have to set the `Background` of the internal `Border` directly (more visual tree traversal).
Layout related attributes like `Width` can be set directly on the `Separator`.

The following example configures the drop location indicator to have a red color:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ListView Loaded="OnListViewLoaded">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" />
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
Optionally, move the following logic to an attached behavior.

```cs
private void OnListViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var listView = sender as ListView;
  if (listView.TryFindVisualChildElement(out GridViewHeaderRowPresenter headerRowPresenter))
  {
    headerRowPresenter.PreviewMouseMove += OnGridViewHeaderRowPresenterPreviewMouseMove;
  }
}

private void OnGridViewHeaderRowPresenterPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.LeftButton is MouseButtonState.Pressed)
  {
    var headerRowPresenter = sender as GridViewHeaderRowPresenter;
    if (headerRowPresenter.TryFindVisualChildElement(out Separator separator))
    {
      if (separator.TryFindVisualChildElement(out Border border))
      {
        border.Background = Brushes.Red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HelperExtensions.cs**

```cs
public static class HelperExtensions
{
  public static bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(this DependencyObject parent, out TChild? resultElement)
    where TChild : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (parent is Popup popup)
    {
      parent = popup.Child;
      if (parent == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
    {
      DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

      if (childElement is TChild child)
      {
        resultElement = child;
        return true;
      }

      if (childElement.TryFindVisualChildElement(out resultElement))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

---

For the sake of completeness, the following example shows how to achieve the same with a `DataGrid`, which exposes a convenient API to fully configure the drop location indicator.
Simply define a `DataGrid.DropLocationIndicatorStyle`:

```xml
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.DropLocationIndicatorStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Separator">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Red" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.DropLocationIndicatorStyle>
</DataGrid>
```